# Which thread do the methods run in?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I want a class which is able to perform a timed task in a thread separate from it's parent, but I am a little confused which thread the various pieces belong to, any information would be appreciated.

My purpose is to make the timed task operate independently from the parent, as there will be more than one of these controlled by a parent wrapping object.

This is what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class timed_load_process {
    private object _lock;
    protected string process;
    protected Timer timer;
    protected bool _abort;
    protected Thread t;

    protected bool aborting { get { lock (_lock) { return this._abort; } } }

    public timed_load_process(string process) {
        this._abort = false;
        this.process = process;
        this.t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.threaded));
        this.t.Start();
    }

    protected void threaded() {
        this.timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.tick), false, 0, 1000);
        while (!this.aborting) {
            // do other stuff
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        this.timer.Dispose();
    }

    protected void tick(object o) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public void abort() { lock (_lock) { this._abort = true; } }
}
```

Since the timer was instantiated inside the thread, does it operate inside the thread `t`, or inside the thread of the `timed_load_process`, and I assume that the operation tick would operate in the same thread as the timer `t`.

Ending up with:

```
public class timed_load_process : IDisposable {
    private object _lock;
    private bool _tick;
    protected string process;
    protected Timer timer;
    protected bool _abort;

    public bool abort {
        get { lock (_lock) { return this._abort; } }
        set { lock (_lock) { this.abort = value; } }
    }

    public timed_load_process(string process) {
        this._abort = false;
        this.process = process;
        this.timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.tick), false, 0, 1000);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        while (this._tick) { Thread.Sleep(100); }
        this.timer.Dispose();
    }

    protected void tick(object o) {
        if (!this._tick) {
            this._tick = true;
            // do stuff
            this._tick = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: What sort of timer is it - no namespaces?

Comment: I inserted the usings above the text, I made this a System.Threading timer.

Comment: Wait ... does this class do anything except start a timer, wait for the timer to fire and do its work, and then exit? If it's not doing anything else, there is a much simpler solution. And do you want the timer to tick only once?

Comment: This task needs to run for a very long time, most likely the uptime of the server it's to be installed on. There is a wrapper which may change the frequency of the timer on demand, or abort the object if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using `System.Threading.Timer`. If so, the `tick` method runs on a pool thread. It is most assuredly *not* the application's main thread.

Just for your info, the Windows Forms timer executes the elapsed event on the GUI thread.

The default behavior for `System.Timers.Timer` is to execute the `Elapsed` event on a pool thread. However, if you set the `SynchronizingObject` to reference a Windows Forms component, the event will be marshaled to the GUI thread.

Comment: So that would mean that I could eliminate the threading part of the process entirely, and the locking too (unless tick accesses fields that could be accessed from without). Letting the timer run it's tick operation without specifically setting up a thread. That would simplify the code a lot :)

Comment: In addition there is no need to create timer in new thread. Also it's better to use ManualResetEvent to block until aborted. Finally it's better to implement IDisposable interface and call timer.Dispose in its Dispose method.

Comment: Based on these comments I think this is the end play: ... adding to main question, since is too long!

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

"The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system."